# Internal Server Error after updating custom Language Model for Watson's speech2text service

Tags: speech-to-text, ibm-watson

We've had success using a custom Language Model for Watson's speech2text service.  However, recently, we decided to extend the model (extended vocabulary, utterances, etc.).  To that end, we reset the model:

```
curl -X POST -u ${credentials} 
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/customizations/${customization_id}/reset"
```

added our extended corpus:

```
curl -X POST -u ${credentials} \
--data-binary @corpus.txt \
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/customizations/${customization_id}/corpora/corpus_test01"
```

verified the process completed, and re-trained the model:

```
curl -X POST -u ${cred} \
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/customizations/${customization_id}/train"
```

Once the process completed ("status": "available"), we were initially able to get responses, and the recognition quality did improve.  However, within a few minutes, we started getting {"error": "Internal Server Error"}.  Can't reset or query. The base model works fine though. Is our only option to create a new model (we would prefer not to)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Revised: don't seem to be able to create a new LM either:

curl -X POST -u ${cred} \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data "{\"name\": \"Test model\", \
  \"base_model_name\": \"en-US_BroadbandModel\", \
  \"description\": \"language model 02\"}" \
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/customizations"

returns:

{
   "code": 500,
   "code_description": "Internal Server Error",
   "error": "Internal Server Error"
}

But base model still works fine ...

New update: LM came back several hours later, out of a blue, and kept working fine through the day.  However, this evening became intermittent, returning "Internal Server Error" with increasing frequency.  Not very usable at this point.

-rg

Comment: We had some issues in that service component around the time you created this thread. But they were resolved shortly after. Are you still experiencing any issues? If that is the case, can you please share your `customization_id` with IBM support so the team can investigate, thanks

Comment: Thanks Dani, that helps.  We have not seen any issues within the last day or so.  Our customization_id is: 166ca6b0-dddd-4eac-99f0-a2a0cb9f4617 if your team wants to have a closer look.  Thanks.